# How to validate the in-time and out-time swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, validation, time

In a given day how to compare time In-Time & Out-Time

Out-Time must greater the In-time

Working Hours:
based on 12 hours timeline
In-Time
09:00 Am
Out-Time
05:00 PM

In-Time
09:00
Out-Time
17:00

based on 24 hours timeline

Alert message print in-time greater out-time not valid

Answer (score -1):

- Get the `yyyy MM dd` string from the *given day*.
- Append the 12-hour or 24-hour time strings.
- Create `Date` instances of In and Out with `DateFormatter`.
- Just compare with `<`